# In Java, when exactly does the post-increment operation occur?

Tags: java, jvm, operators, post-increment

I'm looking at this Java code:

```
        while (n-- != 0) {
            if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
                continue test;
            }
        }
```

I am confused about when, exactly, the `n--` operation takes place. Is it after the `if` statement?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "if loop".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `n--` operation happens each time the `while` condition is evaluated; specifically when the left-hand side of the `!=` operator is evaluated. It has nothing to do with the `if` statement. The `while` condition is evaluated at the start of each loop iteration; if it evaluates to `true`, then the body of the `while` loop (the `if` statement) is executed, but that's well after the `n--` operation has finished. (But of course, then there's the next loop iteration.)

Answer (score 2):

When the while  loop runs for the first time, the value of n is checked if its not equal to zero(because it is post decrement).

Once the condition is evaluated, i.e. after it comes inside the while loop, the value of n will be decremented by one(n-1). And this new value will be used inside the while loop for that particular iteration.

Next iteration when the while loop check the condition, value (n-1) is checked if its equal to zero and so on.

Comment: Actually, when the `while` loop test is evaluated, the value of `n` will be decremented whether or not the loop is entered. So, for instance, if `n == 0` when the `while` loop is first run, then `n` will be `-1` at the statement just after the `while` loop.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you Ted Hopp. :)

Answer (score 1):

`--` or `++` operators if put after operand will happen after the statement that contains it finishes. If put before operand then it will happen before that statement.

In this case the statement is `while` so it will happen after it, meaning after evaluation of condition in the `while` statement.

Comment: The increment or decrement happens when the operator is evaluated, which may occur well before the statement is finished. Thus, a statement like `a[i++] = a[i]` will copy one element into the previous element of array `a`. (That is, the value of `i` when the right-hand side -- `a[i]` -- is evaluated is the value _after_ `i` is incremented by evaluating the [array access expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) `a[i++]` on the left side of the assignment.)